# Use '\g<index> or r'\index' as dict key when use re.sub?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

For example, I have the following string:

```
s = 'Name: @name, ID: @id'
```

Now I want to use `re.sub()` to replace `@name` and `@id`. I know that I can use group to catch some string and then use `'\g<index>'` or `r'\index'` to use  it.

But now I need use it as a dict key, I have this dict:

```
d = {'id': '20', 'name': 'Jon'}
```

And I wish I can get this:

```
s = 'Name: Jon, ID: 20'
```

Also I tried:

```
>>> re.sub('@(\w+)', d[r'\1'], s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '\\1'

>>> re.sub('@(\w+)', d['\g<1>'], s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '\\g<1>'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the function form for `re.sub` in this case. For your basic use case, it could be a simple as:

```
re.sub(r'@(\w+)', lambda m: d[m.group(1)], s)
```

If the logic is more complicated, a top-level `def` is the way to go. Basically, you pass a `callable` instead of a `str`, per the [`re.sub` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Comment: Wow, great! What does `lambda` do here?

Comment: See [`re.sub` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). I'll include a quote in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again :P. Will accept answer in 4 mins.

Comment: @KevinGuan: BTW, a useful thing to note: `callable`s in Python can have state. This has come up before in [another answer of mine for keeping track of the match number in `re.sub`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980674/how-can-i-know-the-match-index-in-a-regular-expression-subns-repl-function/32980816#32980816).

Answer (score 3):

Python provides a [`string.Template` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) (see also [PEP 292](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292/)) which can format strings very similar to kind you are working with. By default the `string.Template` class recognizes `$` as the placeholder. If you change it to `@` (by subclassing `string.Template`) then you can perform the substitutions by calling the [`substitute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template.substitute) or [`safe_substitute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template.safe_substitute) method:

```
import string
class MyTemplate(string.Template):
    delimiter = '@'

content = 'Name: @name, ID: @id'
d = {'id': '20', 'name': 'Jon'}
template = MyTemplate(content)
result = template.safe_substitute(**d)
print(result)
```

prints

```
Name: Jon, ID: 20
```

Comment: Wow, don't know this before :D. But my question is about *use '\g<index> or r'\index' as dict key when use re.sub*. So I can't accept this. But good to know :)

Comment: Thanks i did not know this cool stuff! Another trick in hat!

Answer (score 0):

If formatting your string differently is an option, you can do it this way:

```
>>> d = {'id': '20', 'name': 'Jon'}
>>> 'Name: {name}, ID: {id}'.format(**d)
'Name: Jon, ID: 20'
```

Comment: But my string isn't formatted in this format...however a good suggestion.